# Color swatch and text swatch issue in magento 2

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute

If I used color and text swatch in magento 2, sequence/order of option isn't changing. I mean I want to show

```
1. size
2. color
```

but it always show

```
1. color
2. size
```

if I used dropdown instead of color and text swatch. it is working fine.
Can anyone tell me, is that isssue comes with magento 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue just today and able to fix it by changing each attribute key as string by adding any character like "_" in the getJsonConfig result. It seems its a browser or javascript issue where it automatically sort numeric array keys so changing it to string key will prevent it from sorting automatically.

**Testing Solution:**
 1. Edit `vendor\magento\module-swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable.php`
 2. Add the below function to override the getJsonConfig:

```
public function getJsonConfig() {
        $jsonConfig = parent::getJsonConfig();
        $decodedConfig = json_decode($jsonConfig, true);

        foreach ($decodedConfig['attributes'] as $attributeId => $attributeData) {
            $decodedConfig['attributes']["_" . $attributeId] = $attributeData;
            unset($decodedConfig['attributes'][$attributeId]);
        }

        return $this->jsonEncoder->encode($decodedConfig);
    }
```

You have two choices, either use plugin or extend that file. I use plugin for this.

Hope that helps :)